# Can we modify this code to return the name of a method instead of a property?

Tags: c#

Looking for a clean way to discover the string name of a method in a type safe way.

Here is what I have for properties, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it for methods.

```
class Program
{
    class Customer
    {
        public String Id { get; set; }
    }

    public static String GetPropertyName<T>(
        Expression<Func<T, Object>> selector) where T : class
    {
        var expression = (MemberExpression)selector.Body;
        return expression.Member.Name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String propertyName = GetPropertyName<Customer>(c => c.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What would the example usage look like? `GetMethodName<Foo>(f => f.Method)` or `GetMethodName<Foo>(f => f.Method(valid, args))` or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much by changing to:

```
    var expression = (MethodCallExpression)selector.Body;
    return expression.Method.Name;
```

with the notable exception that you will need an `Action<T>` option to handle `void` methods. You will have to supply dummy parameter values, of course - if you *really* want you can obtain those too.

Actually, your *existing* code might not be robust; you may need to throw away a cast operation (to box the int to an object).

```
public static string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Func<T, Object>> selector) where T : class
{
    var expression = (MethodCallExpression)(selector.Body is UnaryExpression ? ((UnaryExpression)selector.Body).Operand : selector.Body);
    return expression.Method.Name;
}
public static string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> selector) where T : class
{
    var expression = (MethodCallExpression)(selector.Body is UnaryExpression ? ((UnaryExpression)selector.Body).Operand : selector.Body);
    return expression.Method.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, our code base uses the following:

```
public class TypeHelper
{
    private static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInternal(LambdaExpression p)
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression;

        if (p.Body is UnaryExpression)
        {
            UnaryExpression ue = (UnaryExpression)p.Body;
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)ue.Operand;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = (MemberExpression)p.Body;
        }
        return (PropertyInfo)(memberExpression).Member;
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameInternal(p);
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<TObject, T>(Expression<Func<TObject, T>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameInternal(p);
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameInternal(p);
    }

    public static string GetPropertyName(Expression p)
    {
        return GetPropertyNameInternal((LambdaExpression) p);
    }

    private static string GetPropertyNameInternal(LambdaExpression p)
    {
        return GetPropertyInternal(p).Name;
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<TObject>(Expression<Func<TObject, object>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyInternal(p);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<TObject, T>(Expression<Func<TObject, T>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyInternal(p);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo GetProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T>> p)
    {
        return GetPropertyInternal(p);
    }
}
```

That gives you the ability to do:

```
var propertyName = TypeHelper.GetPropertyName<Customer>(c => c.Id);
```

Or

```
var propertyName = TypeHelper.GetPropertyName(() => this.Id); // If inside Customer class
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have `System.Web.Mvc`, you can use `ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression)`, like so:

```
Expression<Func<Response, string>> expression = r => r.Message;
Assert.AreEqual("Message", ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression));
```

(`Response` being a custom class with a Message property.)