# Get name of a method strongly typed

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

Think that I have a class like below:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Square(int a)
    {
        return a * a;
    }
}
```

All you know that i can write a method that returns name of given property:

```
var name = GetPropertyName<Foo>(f => f.Bar); //returns "Bar"
```

GetPropertyName method can be implemented easily as below:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> exp)
{
    var body = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (body == null)
    {
        var ubody = (UnaryExpression)exp.Body;
        body = ubody.Operand as MemberExpression;
    }
    return body.Member.Name;
}
```

But I want to get a method name as easily as property name like below:

```
var name1 = GetMethodName<Foo>(f => f.Sum); //expected to return "Sum"
var name2 = GetMethodName<Foo>(f => f.Square); //expected to return "Square"
```

Is it possible to write such a GetMethodName method?

Note that: GetMethodName must be independent from signature or return value of the given method.

Comment: Is there any chance that you know before hand the method `f.Sum` but still want to pass it in another method returning just the string `"Sum"`? It doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Try to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438701/can-we-modify-this-code-to-return-the-name-of-a-method-instead-of-a-property

Comment: Instead of `f => f.Sum` just use `Foo.Sum`

Comment: @leppie it's signature is incompatible with `Func<T, object>`

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: So overload `GetMethodName` (for all the variations ;p)

Comment: @leppie yes, I also thought about that. But tried to find out the most generic form of parameters. Got the error `Cannot convert method group 'Sum' to non-delegate type 'System.Delegate`, which is ok, just funny a bit

Comment: @IlyaIvanov This is the exact result when I try to create such a method. It gives the same error. But there must be a way of sending an arbitrary delegate to he GetMethodName method.

Comment: @KingKing This was an example only. But think that I will send the name to a library that will use it. Also I dont want to write "Sum" as hardcoded string since it's not safe. Maybe I will rename method and this string must be changed in this case.

Comment: There is an article for that: http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/linq-beyond-queries-strong-typed-reflection/ But it is not as simple as easy as I want.

Comment: @hikalkan writing `"Sum"` is not hardcoded, when you can pass `f.Sum` in, you can always use the result `"Sum"` instead. **Unless you have a list of delegates and need to loop through that list and get the corresponding method name in each loop**

Comment: You could check out how MOQ does it. https://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart. They're using the It.IsAny<T> to pass in parameters so c# could pick the right method.

Comment: @KingKing What if I refactor my class and rename method Sum, the string "Sum" will be old. That's my case.

Comment: @hikalkan well, if so there is no other choice. However I think you should avoid refactoring code that way, at least that may make some night-mare for `Reflection`, you can imagine that some old code uses reflection with your class to get the method `Sum` by passing in the string `"Sum"`, it won't work anymore if you rename it to another. I'm pretty happy that `.NET framework` has been rarely refactored that way.

Comment: @KingKing .NET framework is not being refactored surely. Even if it changes name of a method, this method is marked as obsolete and it like a long time. But user code for an enterprise application may change frequently. So, I don't think to develop a library that's method names changes frequently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research, I've found that `Expression<Action<T>>` should be sufficient to do what you want.

```
private string GetMethodName<T>(Expression<Action<T>> method)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)method.Body).Method.Name;
}

public void TestMethod()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName<Foo>(x => foo.Square(1)));
    Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName<Foo>(x => foo.Sum(1,1)));
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }

    public int Sum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    public int Square(int a)
    {
        return a * a;
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: now put `SayHello` into a different class or try a method with a different signature

Comment: `GetMethodName(person.SayHello)` returns `"SayHello"`

Comment: Makes the usage more annoying since you now need to declare a variable of that type. Interaction between different method signatures and overload resolution is ugly as well.

Comment: @WillFaithfull Thanks for answer. This is the best solution until now. But, indeed, it's not what I want. This approach requires pass dummy values to the method but it seems a little bad. It will be perfect if possible to write just Console.WriteLine(GetMethodName<Foo>(x => foo.Sum)); but not possible as I see.